# Complex permutation/probability problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

It's been a long time since I have done combinations and permutations and I've never done a course in probability and things of the like, so this problem is being difficult for me. Here it goes:

I have 3 lists of exactly 6 values each in a specific order (I'm not sure how else to call them, since sets don't care about order by default).

For example:

```
list-1: {a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1}
list-2: {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2}
list-3: {a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3}
```

For list-1 and list-2, each value ranges from 0 to 31. **31 is considered a good value, anything else is a bad value.**

Then, we want to give values to list-3 by randomly selecting either a random-integer (ranging from 0 to 31, denoted as `random-integer(0, 31)`)  or one of the respective values from list-1 and list-2.

For example:

For assigning a value to a3, we randomly pick either a1, a2, or a random-integer from 0 to 31.
Here is a representation in pseudo-code in case it is easier to understand that way:

```
a3 = random-pick(a1, a2, random-integer(0, 31))
b3 = random-pick(b1, b2, random-integer(0, 31))
etc..
```

This is done for all values of list-3.

However there is another constraint, once a random-integer has been generated, the remaining choices for the remaining values of list-3 are then restricted to only the respective values in list-1 and list-2.

Example #1:

```
a3 = random-pick(a1, a2, random-integer(0, 31)) = random-integer(0, 31)
b3 = random-pick(b1, b2) = b1
c3 = random-pick(c1, c2) = c2
d3 = random-pick(d1, d2) = d2
etc...
```

Example #2:

```
a3 = random-pick(a1, a2, random-integer(0, 31)) = a2
b3 = random-pick(b1, b2, random-integer(0, 31)) = b1
c3 = random-pick(c1, c2, random-integer(0, 31)) = random-integer(0, 31)
d3 = random-pick(d1, d2) = d1
e3 = random-pick(e1, e2) = e2
f3 = random-pick(f1, f2) = f2
```

Example #3:

```
a3 = random-pick(a1, a2, random-integer(0, 31)) = a2
b3 = random-pick(b1, b2, random-integer(0, 31)) = b1
c3 = random-pick(c1, c2, random-integer(0, 31)) = c2
d3 = random-pick(d1, d2, random-integer(0, 31)) = d2
e3 = random-pick(e1, e2, random-integer(0, 31)) = e2
f3 = random-integer(0, 31) = random-integer(0, 31)
```

Looking at the examples (I'm not sure how to explain it verbally altogether) it can be concluded that **there must be 1 and only 1 `random-integer(0, 31)` between all 6 values of list-3.**

---

The question is the following:
**How would I go about making a formula (or what is the formula) or what procedure should I follow, in order to calculate the probability (%) of getting a specific permutation of good values (31) for list-3?**

---

Extra help/hint by simplifying the problem:

It helped me to assume for a second that instead of being `random-integer(0, 31)`, it would be `random-integer(0,30)`, thus only generating bad values. And in addition to it, I would also assume that the placement and the quantity of a random-integer generated would not matter in the equation.

Then the following example:

```
list-1: 3, 31, 31, 12, 31, 31 
list-2: 31, 21, 31, 14, 31, 19
```

with the following problem, could be solved in the following way:

```
Probability-of-getting-good-values ( list-3 == {31, 31, 31, xx, 31, xx} )
= 1/3 * 1/3 * 2/3 * 1 * 2/3 * 1
= 0.04938
= 4.938 % chance
```

Where `xx` denotes that it expects nothing, `31` denotes a good value, and `Probability-of-getting-good-values( list )` is the function for calculating the probability of the said permutation happening.
Since a1 = 3 and b1 = 31, and a bad value might come up as well, there are 3 possibilities out of which 1 is a good one, thus place 1/3 for the initial factor. Same deal with a2 and b2. For the third value a3 = b3 = 31, so both are good values, and since it is considered that a bad value may still come up (remember in this case we decided to ditch some conditions), then 2 out of 3 possible values are good values, thus 2/3 as the third factor. 
For the fourth factor, a value of 1 would be used since we only care about good values, and since in the 4th one it doesn't expect anything, then the result does not change.
And so on.

However, the moment I decide to implement the conditions/constraints ommited in this example is when I get stuck with not knowing how to go about it.

Note: This is not homework, but rather a personal self-assigned problem/project.
Thank you for your help. Let me know if anything needs to be fixed.